# ExpressJS/Node ajax login

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, mongoose, everyauth

Hi I am using the express framework to make a site in node. I am trying to use facebox to present a box where a use can login so that the music on the site will not have to stop playing.

I am using mongoose-auth/everyauth for authentication and can't figure out how this can be done.

I need to be able to render the login page as a partial I believe. I have the following:
I think using loginLocals is the answer?

Anyone have any idea!?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema
    , mongooseAuth = require('mongoose-auth');

var everyauth = require('everyauth')
    , Promise = everyauth.Promise;

    var UserSchema = new Schema({});
    UserSchema.plugin(mongooseAuth, {
        everymodule: {
            everyauth: {
                User: function () {
                    return User;
                }
            }
        },
                 password: {
                    loginWith: 'email'
                  , extraParams: {
                                    genre: String
                    }
                  , everyauth: {
                        getLoginPath: '/login'
                      , postLoginPath: '/login'
                      , loginView: 'login.jade'
                      , getRegisterPath: '/register'
                      , postRegisterPath: '/register'
                      , registerView: 'register.jade'
                      , loginSuccessRedirect: '/'
                      , registerSuccessRedirect: '/'

                                , loginLocals: function(req, res) {
                                    //console.log("ASD");
                                return res.partial('toop');
                                }
                    }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your users to be able to log in via Everyauth without your music stopping then you can't do it with a lightbox like facebox. You need AJAX to keep your page loaded (and hence your music playing) but OAuth doesn't work over AJAX because it relies on redirects.

You need to do something like this:

- When the user clicks to log in on page "A", open a new pop-up window "B" pointing to your login process
- Everyauth will redirect window "B" to the relevant OAuth provider
- The user will authenticate and grant permissions
- Window "B" will be redirected back to your site
- You need to pick up the end of the process and from pop-up window "B" you need to communicate to window "A" that the user has logged in successfully. You can either do that directly with Javascript, or by letting the server inform the original page (via websockets, comet, polling etc.)
- Your music will have been playing the entire time in window "A"